# Hide page title on Views 3

Tags: views, theming, 7

There doesn't seem to be a concise answer of how to hide the page view title on a rendered views page. Does anyone know how to hide this without having to install another module or write any code? Is it even possible?

Comment: Wouldn't having a rendered views page imply you're already adding code? If so, you should be able to unset it before rendering it. If you can use views_embed_view(), it doesn't return the title.